# Can i predict data price based on a survey on azure machine learning?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to predict my input price based on a list of questions/answers using azure machine learning.
I built one using  the "bayesian linear regression" but it seems that it is predicting the price based on the prices i have in my dataset and not based on the Q/A.
Am i in the wrong path or am i missing something?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the Q/A s that you using is not having missing values. If there's any missing values follow data preprocessing techniques to fill those.
2. What kind of answers do you have as inputs? (yes/no, numeric values, different textual answers, etc...) In  my opinion numerical values and yes/no inputs makes your model more accurate.
3. Try different regression algorithms (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-algorithm-cheat-sheet/) and check their accuracy.

Comment: i filled missing values with 0.
I edited my answers to be categorical, i originaly have them as numeric ie id of the answer

Comment: It's bit hard to come up with an exact answer without seeing the dataset. See whether your model can be mapped into a non-linear regression. It might give a better output. Re-check the outliers & remove those first.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set features and label properly. if you publish your experiment in Gallery using unlisted mode and paste the link here, we can take a look.

Comment: I am actually not authorised to do so but if have any documents that can help me that would appreciated.

Comment: I also have q/a set as features and price set as label.
would that be it?

Comment: Can you check that your predictive label is a numeric by enforcing through meta-data editor?

Comment: it is numeric. in second tests it seems that i'm predicting correctly based on the q/a. in my opinion the problem why i'm not getting good estimation is that i don't have enough data to train better the model.